# scanf and whitespace characters

Tags: c, char, int, scanf

I am doing a simple example related to scanf()

```
int a, b;
printf("Please enter int a:\n);
scanf("%d",&a);//line 1
printf("Please enter int b:\n);
scanf("%d",&b);//line 2
```

I run this code at a I put 45, and b 78, so the input buffer looks like this: 45\n78\n, line1 takes 45 ignores \n, and line2 ignores \n takes 78 and ignores \n

```
char ch, ch2;
printf("Please enter char ch:\n);
scanf("%c",&ch);//line3
printf("Please enter char ch2:\n);
scanf("%c",&ch2);//line4
```

I debugged this code and I thought of putting 'a' in ch, and 'b' in ch2, so the input buffer will look like this: a\nb\n, line3 takes 'a' ignores \n and line4 ignores \n takes 'b' and ignores \n

I thought this would happen, but when I debugged it line3 takes 'a', and line4 reads \n and stores it.

I don't understand I thought scanf() is supposed to ignore whitespace characters.

as you can see here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Note that you are missing corresponding double quotes in your code.

Comment: @machine_1 yeah that is only in the post not in the code, I will edit it right away

Comment: The `%c`, `%[]`, and `%n` directives do _not_ skip leading whitespace characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> **%c**
>
> Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no terminating null byte is added). **The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed**. To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.

Comment: makes sense, the %c specifier won't suppress leading whitespace characters.
Thanks for the comment